# Recursion condensing concentric circles by 10% while staying relative to center

Tags: java, recursion, geometry

The right circle is not using recursion but I want the recursive one(left) to look similar. Might be to little code will provide more if needed. It's the equation to keep the condensing circles stick to the center that i'm struggling with. Thank you any help would be appreciated.

```
// Initial attempt      
      if (diameter >= 20) {
        double newDiameter = diameter * .9;
        drawCircles(newDiameter, xCorner += deltaDiameter * 2, yCorner += deltaDiameter * 2, g2);
    }

 // Working code
    if (diameter >= 20) {
        double newDiameter = diameter - deltaDiameter;
        drawCircles(newDiameter, xCorner += (deltaDiameter / 2), yCorner += 
       (deltaDiameter / 2), g2);
    }
```

Comment: @NanduKalidindi Here is my entire recursive method.

Comment: So, xCorner and yCorner are not the center coordinates is it?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi I don't believe so. Parameters passed to constructor is where I instantiated eye1. Added some more code below horizontal rule.

Answer (score 2):

Since `xCorner` and `yCorner` are the upper left coordinates, new coordinates are to be calculated properly. Please try putting in this piece of code, I will add more info into the answer soon. This is assuming your initial `diameter=255`; `xCorner=0`; `yCorner=10` and `deltaDiameter=10`

This is the approximation diagram of how the calculation is done.

[image]

```
if (diameter >= 20) {
    double newDiameter = diameter - deltaDiameter;
    // System.out.println(xCorner + 255);
    drawCircles(newDiameter, xCorner += (1.414 * 0.5 * deltaDiameter), yCorner += (1.414 * 0.5 * deltaDiameter), g2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this code to work off your code.  `if (diameter >= 20) {
   double newDiameter = diameter - deltaDiameter;
   drawCircles(newDiameter, xCorner += (deltaDiameter / 2), yCorner += (deltaDiameter / 2), g2);
  }`